# Help dealing with spam logic

Tags: php, captcha, spam, recaptcha

I have a blog, and i have decided to use Akismet and reCaptcha for spam filtering, the way i am dealing with spam is

a) the user should go through the captcha before posting a comment
b) Now even if some spam bypass captcha then i would like Akismet to handle it.

For akismet to handle the Spam, i thought of creating two different tables in database for comments, One to store the comments which is not detected by Akismet , The other is to store the Comments that is detected by akismet(Spam). the reason behind this logic is i thought may be i don't want to mess my comments table with spam  so only i thought of storing the Spam detected messages in different table.

Now the problem is duplication of table will exist if i use this methodology. instead i could add an extra column in the table to check and store wether it is a spam. i could do either way.

which one will be wise to adopt. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching two tables is not an efficient approach, nor is it any easier code-wise. Just combine the tables and filter the data regularly. Besides, Akismet already has its own spam database. No value is added by maintaining your own copy of spam. Probably the only reason for maintaining such is that you foresee network disconnects on certain occasions, then that's the only time you have to resort to your own internal database lookups.

Answer (score 1):

### The [reCaptcha](http://recaptcha.net/) is pretty strong itself.

The reCaptch support's official answer about **[reCAPTCHA strength, uptime, and longevity](http://groups.google.com/group/recaptcha/browse_thread/thread/61eda9ea6cea0b84/8f2ba51dc6fd32a4?pli=1)**:

> All we can tell you is 
>   that, to the best of our knowledge, reCAPTCHA remains unbroken, despite 
>   being used to protect many notorious sites. We monitor our system closely, 
>   and can react to attacks very quickly.

Why do you even need Akismet after letting users through reCaptcha ?